# cpu high usage with postgres.exe

Tags: postgresql

I work with PostgreSQL 9.0

I used windows server 2008

I have problem with cpu high usage  it arrived to 100 %

my application it used between by 600 and 700 users

I have this config in postgres.conf

```
max_connections = 750   
shared_buffers = 8GB    
temp_buffers = 32MB 
work_mem = 64MB             
maintenance_work_mem = 1GB
effective_cache_size = 24GB
```

and this is my config in applicationContext-db.xml

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
   <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
     <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://srvdatabase:5432/DBTest"/>
    <property name="username" value="postgres"/>
    <property name="password" value="postgres"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="750"/>
    <property name="maxIdle" value="30"/>
    <property name="maxWait" value="20000"/>
    <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="true"/>
    <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true"/>
    <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="300"/>
</bean>
```

sametime the cpu it's performence is lower than 50%

but sametimes it arrived to 100% and in this time my application will be down

Comment: Apparently you are running some very complex SQL queries. You need to tune those statements.

Comment: I fail to see a question here.

Comment: "max_connections = 750 ", that doesn't work. If you need that many connections, use a connection pool and just a few connections between the pool and the database. Most hardware works best with just 20 to 60 concurrent database connections.